# Supposed to be.. or supposed to have/has been

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. He is supposed *to be* actor when he was younger.
> 2. He is supposed *to have been* actor when he was younger.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Neither. *He **was** supposed . . .* With that, either would be correct. (Assuming you also added an article in front of *actor*.)

Comment: Number 2 could be correct but it would have a different meaning than I think is intended.

Comment: Surely (2) means 'It is believed that he was an actor when he was younger'.? 'He was supposed to be...' would mean that the belief was current when he was young, or that he had intended to become an actor in his youth but didn't.